# Signup/Register user using quickblox?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am using arabic text to signup on quickblox

```
http://api.quickblox.com/users
```

But i am receiving this error in iOS XCode

```
"errors":{"login":["should contain alphanumeric and punctuation characters only"],"password":["should contain alphanumeric and punctuation characters only"]}}
```

Is it possible to signup using credentials in arabic? i.e. login & password in arabic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arabic language isn't supported for authentication using `quickblox` I'm afraid. Please use English for authentication. You can convert Arabic text into base64 string for authentication in `quickblox`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :)

Answer (score 0):

Arabic language is not supported. Please use English for signing up.